# G+ Domain API Google Apps Script Public Posts Scan

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-plus

I'm running a script that scans our domain users G+ posts and flags any post shared publicly and then sends an email notification with a link to the post to the end user. The script was written by someone else who is no longer with the company. I want to change the script so that it will flag any post that does not have `"domainRestricted";True`.

Here's an output of a scanned post with the type of access associated `"domainRestricted":True`. This post is shared within the domain.

```
{
  "description":"Shared privately",
  "domainRestricted":true,
  "kind":"plus#acl"
}
```

Here's an output example of a scanned post without `domainRestricted` access. This post is shared with a Circle containing users outside of the domain, essentially Public.

```
{
  "description":"Shared privately",
  "kind":"plus#acl"
}
```

Here's an output example of a scanned post with `Public` as the access. This post was explicitly shared publicly.

```
{
  "items":[{"type":"public"}],
  "description":"Public",
  "kind":"plus#acl"
}
```

I want to change this code, to scan for any posts that does not contain the access `"domainRestricted":True`.

```
function checkPublicPosts( userId ) {    
  var publicPosts = Array();
  var pageToken;

  try {
    do {
      Logger.log( 'Scanning posts by ' + userId );

      // Search for all Google Plus posts by userId
      posts = PlusDomains.Activities.list( userId, 'user', {
        maxResults: 100,
        pageToken: pageToken
      });

      // If posts are found, check to see if they are public
      if( posts.items ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < posts.items.length; i++ ) {
          var post = posts.items[i];

          var public = false;
          if( !post.access.domainRestricted && ( typeof( post.access.items ) != 'undefined' ) ) {
            for( var j = 0; j < post.access.items.length; j++ ) {
              if( post.access.items[j].type = 'public' ) {
                public = true;
                j = post.access.items.length;
              }
            }
          }

          // If a post is public, add it to the list of public posts for userId
          if( public ) publicPosts.push( post );
        }
      }

      // If user has more than 100 posts, continue with the analysis of subsequent batches of 100
      pageToken = posts.nextPageToken;

    } while (pageToken);

  } catch( err ) {
    // The code above sometimes fails for unexpected reasons. We
    // log this error.

    Logger.log( 'Failed on ' + userId + ' with error ' + err );
  }                      
  return publicPosts;
}
```

Can anyone help me?